# To manipulate URL based on coming URL by PHP

Tags: php, get

**How can you manipulate the destination URL by the name of the starting url?**

My URL is

```
www.example.com/index.php?ask_question
```

I do the following manipulation in the destination URL

```
    if ($_GET['ask_question']) {                        
            // Problem HERE, since if -clause is always false
        if ( $login_cookie_original == $login_cookie )
        {
            include "/codes/handlers/handle_login_status.php";
            header("Location: /codes/index.php?ask_question");
            die("logged in - send your question now");
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to replace that with:

```
if (isset($_GET['ask_question'])) {
```

Which will only be true if it's contained in the URL.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (isset($_GET['ask_question'])) {          
    ...
```

If you did a print_r() of $_GET you would see

```
Array
(
    [ask_question] => 
)
```

which shows that ask_question is set, but is empty, so it tests false.

Comment: I have this `print_r($_GET['ask_question']);` in my body. It returns nothing in all pages, not even at http://localhost/codes/index.php?ask_question.

Answer (score 2):

```
$location = "test.php";
if(isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']))
{
    header("Location:".$location . "?" . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}
else
{
    header("Location:".$location);
}
```

Comment: This answer shows me that I need to use different method to get the URL of the site which the user last visited. - I know that I can get that data in Google Analytics, but I am not sure how I can get it by PHP.

Comment: I opened a new thread based on your answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250729/to-get-the-coming-url-of-the-user

Answer (score 1):

you could possibly check the $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] variable to see if it contains 'ask_question'

edit: fixed the typo

Comment: should be $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve values after the question mark by using the [`$_GET`](http://php.net/reserved.variables.get) super global. For the example `?ask_question=true`.

```
//is ask_question true?
if($_GET['ask_question'] == 'true') {
    echo 'ask_question is true';
} else {
    echo 'ask_question is not true';
}
```

For variables without values (like `?hello`), use [`$_GET`](http://php.net/reserved.variables.get) in such way:

```
if(isset($_GET['hello'])) {
    echo 'hello is there';
} else {
    echo 'hello is not there';
}
```

You've asked a lot of very basic questions about PHP and you don't seem to have a grasp on how the language works. I suggest giving the documentation a good read before your next question.

> - [**PHP Documention Home**](http://php.net/manual)
> - [PHP: Variables From External Sources](http://php.net/variables.external)